# Using Excel VBA to Select a filtered range where results will vary

Tags: excel, select, filtering, copy-paste, vba

I am working with a spreadsheet to produce a report. The data will vary depending on the department for which I am reporting. I need to select the records in column A that are the result of a filter and paste them in column B, once pasted I need to clear the cells in column A then remove the filter. I have been able to accommodate the variable criteria for the filter; however, my problem is with selecting the variable range. The data to be selected will never start in cell A2, any cell after that is fair game. How do I select a range that varies? How do I have the User interact with the macro to select the cells?

This works for me to filter by all my variables.

```
Cells.Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$F$65000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array( _
"1000", "1001", "1005", "ZBIL", "1002", "1003", "1004", "1006", "1007", "1008", "1009", "AOMS",      "ASPS", "NATL", "ZCON", "ZREP"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
On Error Resume Next
```

I am using the following to select the range, the first line works to select the data to be copied (although it still selects the cell A1 and I would prefer not to have that cell selected). The second line returns an error "Object doesn't support this property or method. I have tried range select ToRight however I end up with the entire sheet selected.

```
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection(Selection, Selection.xlToRight).Select
Selection.FillRight
```

I appreciate any assistance that is available.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the range of the visible rows after applying an advanced filter in Excel (VBA)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370286/how-to-get-the-range-of-the-visible-rows-after-applying-an-advanced-filter-in-ex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be the most efficient solution, but you can loop through all the cells/rows and check if the filter hid them:

```
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer

With ActiveSheet
    lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 3 To lastrow
        If .Rows(i).Hidden = False Then
            .Cells(i, 2).Value = .Cells(i, 1).Value
            .Cells(i, 1).Value = ""
        End If
    Next i

End With
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked however I am still missing some of the data.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked after I added an on Error Resume next before my filter criteria.

Comment: Using On Error Resume Next can be dangerous - it skips over errors in the code, instead of forcing you to fix them.  I recommend removing it and addressing the issue that is causing the errors.