# in .NET Excel VSTO can I identify the rows currently visible in the active window?

Tags: .net, excel, scroll, vsto

I have a VSTO project that interfaces with a database to pull information into an Excel worksheet.  I would like to determine if the last row pulled in from the database is currently visible in the window, and if not (and only if not) scroll the window to make it visible.  Is there any way to determine if a row/cell/range is in the active window view or the range of rows/cells visible in the active window view?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do it via the [ActivePane](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840981.aspx) property of the [ActiveWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835855.aspx). Then use the [VisibleRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff193038.aspx) property of the ActivePane.

If you will have problems with the ActivePane you might want to read my article about the [Excel bug with the ActivePane](http://bezensek.com/blog/2014/07/23/excel-activepane-index-property-bug-and-a-workaround/) when Freeze panes are activated.

Answer (score 0):

The [SpecialCells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157(v=office.15).aspx) returns a Range object that represents all the cells that match the specified type and value. You just need to pass the **xlCellTypeVisible** value to get visible cells. See [How to get the range of the visible rows after applying an advanced filter in Excel (VBA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370286/how-to-get-the-range-of-the-visible-rows-after-applying-an-advanced-filter-in-ex) for more information.

Also you may find the [Show](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838617(v=office.15).aspx) method which scrolls through the contents of the active window to move the range into view. The range must consist of a single cell in the active document.