# Best way to Return an Excel named table which is filtered as a range (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel Table called myData (2013 functionality). My intention is to output a listbox with the first two columns from that table BUT only after autofilter has been applied. I cannot seem to find a way to reference the table as a range for only that filtered table.

Something like this:

```
Dim appsTable As ListObject
Set appsTable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AppData").ListObjects("myData")
    Dim Table1Range As range
Set Table1Range = appsTable.range
   'Set Table1DataBodyRange = appsTable.DataBodyRange
   'Worksheets(1).Range("myData[AppName]")
   Dim selectedCells As range
Set selectedCells = appsTable.Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So after a user filters the table, you want to populate the listboxes with only the visible rows?

Comment: I actually want to populate a listbox with 2 columns, the "PK" of the table and the cellref to the table. then I have a form which will assist with population of the data. so yes. once a table is filtered i want o populate a listbox (in another sheet) with the first column of the original table (and a row number of that table)

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify my question a little more. You want the listbox to populate with all the data from 2 columns after a table is filtered? Something like an `OnFilter` event? Or, the list gets filtered, you want to populate the listbox with only the visible data from the 2 columns? Eg, rows 4-10 get hidden so only the 2 columns from rows 1-3 and 10-n are displayed?

Comment: yes. your second scenario is correct. So the filtered table with rows 4-10 are hidden. then on a button, I want to reference the table range which only includes the non-filtered records (well I only want the first two columns)

Comment: Ah! See this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370286/how-to-get-the-range-of-the-visible-rows-after-applying-an-advanced-filter-in-ex

Comment: Thanks. I did see that one, I have the solution "appsTable.Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)" but that doesnt work with appsTable.Rows