# With vb.net change in excel some cell values with activated filter metod

Tags: excel, vb.net

I want to go through all visible (non hidden rows) and change data in cell 4.
But the important thing is that there in some cells data already exists and this data should not be changed and not been counted in the input rows. So i have filtered all the rows with 0.00 value in cell 4, and now i want to input from visible rows 2 to 500 the value 70 in cell 4, than from 501 to 1251 value 65 and from 1252 to the last used row value 60.
Unfortunately, i am lost, completely. Please help

```
Dim numrows As Integer = oBook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count()
Dim numrows2 As Integer = oBook.Worksheets(2).UsedRange.Rows.Count()
wsheet2 = oBook.Worksheets(2)
wsheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)

Dim currentRow As Long
oBook.Worksheets(1).Range("A11").AutoFilter(Field:=11, Criteria1:="=", VisibleDropDown:=False)

If wsheet.Rows().Hidden = False Then
    For currentRow = 2 To numrows Step 1
      If String.IsNullOrEmpty(wsheet2.Cells(currentRow, 11).Value) Then
         If currentRow >= 2 And currentRow <= 501 Then
            wsheet.Cells(currentRow, 11).value = "70"
         ElseIf currentRow >= 501 And currentRow <= 1251 Then
            wsheet.Cells(currentRow, 11).value = "65"
         ElseIf currentRow >= 1252 Then
            wsheet.Cells(currentRow, 11).value = "60"
         End If
      End If
    Next
End If
```

The point is i.e. from row 2 to 500 there are 10 cells with inserted data "0.00", so the correct input would be to row 510 with the value 70, and so on...Thats why i hidded the 0.00 rows, but there are still be filled with the given values 70, 65 and 60

[image]

Comment: Your check for row is visible should probably be inside the loop. You also need to pass a row number into the `Rows()` method. In your case, you would pass in `currentRow`. I'm still trying to decipher what you are trying to do. Once I figure it out I will post an answer.

Comment: Also, this might be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370286/how-to-get-the-range-of-the-visible-rows-after-applying-an-advanced-filter-in-ex

Comment: ok I will try to explain :)
So my code opens an excel file, runs a macro, edit it and save it i an folder.
The only problem i have with editing it. What i need in total is:
- In the excel files there are 4 columns, the 4-th column is a "price" column
- the macro i already run calculates and writes already the rows that costs nothing an writes the value 0.00 in the 4-th cell, all other rows need to be priced
- when i calculate the price, say it from 0-500, it should jump over the 0.00 cells/rows and continue to input 500 times the desired price

Comment: Your loop is writing to column 11. Can you add a screen shot or mock up a table so this can be visualized better?

Comment: How can I add a screenshot here, don’t see any possibility.

Comment: Here i uploaded the screenshot: https://paste.pics/7780bb817252cb3dfde95f2190920f5f

Comment: I added the screen shot for you..it's being peer reviewed and will show up soon. You can go back and look at it to learn how it works. I'll review this and hopefully come up with a solution. Having the image should help other users see what you're trying to do so they can help more easily too.

Comment: So what's in the other sheet? You are declaring two sheets. `wsheet` and `wsheet2`

Comment: It’s exactly the same just for another price calculation. So in other words i need just one to work and copy the statement for the other sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments in your post, I think you can simply copy your sheet to a second sheet when you're done. I might be understanding this wrong though. I modified your loop to what I think you are trying to do.

I don't think you need the filter. You can simply test the cell on each row and determine if you want to do anything with that row.

```
    Dim numrows As Integer = oBook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count()
    wsheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)

    Dim currentRow As Long

Dim counter As Long
counter = 0

For currentRow = 2 To numrows Step 1
  If wsheet.Cells(currentRow, 11).Value Is Nothing Then
     counter += 1
     If counter >= 2 And counter <= 500 Then
        wsheet.Cells(currentRow, 11).value = "70"
     ElseIf counter >= 501 And counter <= 1251 Then
        wsheet.Cells(currentRow, 11).value = "65"
     ElseIf counter >= 1252 Then
        wsheet.Cells(currentRow, 11).value = "60"
     End If
  End If
Next
```

Comment: This code brings me an error: System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.'

I have changed it to:  If wsheet.Cells(currentRow, 11).Value is nothing then...

that works, but ist still counting strictly to all rows even the 0.00 value rows. See this screenshot: https://paste.pics/3412e3c9b9621150461ddc9e152e87da

Comment: Actually, to row 501 there are 10 values with 0.00, so the "65" value should actually start from 511. I hope that it is now a little bit clearer

Comment: What if you change it to `wsheet.Cells(currentRow, 11).Value <> 0`

Comment: then it dont input the values, https://paste.pics/ef6ccb8cf2f78ac244c5ff81ff3df793

Comment: I just noticed overlap in your if and first else with row 501. Also, I'm still a bit confused because your screenshot a couple comments up shows a nicely populated sheet. Can you explain what exactly is wrong in that screenshot.

Comment: Yes i see that now to thx, i will change the first entry to <= 500.
But the problem still is that in the exel file, there sould be 500 rows/cells with the value 70, but not changing the 0.00 cells, then 750 cells with the value 65 and every other row with the value 60.

Comment: Ok, I tried something else in my answer using a counter variable. I'm not sure if this is what you want, but it is how I am reading into it.

Comment: Perfect, you are my hero :) that is exactly what I needed. There where few customizations needed in the numbers. So that the calculations are correct.

Comment: I'm am happy I was able to help you.