# Is it possible to use VBA code on a already filtered sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with about 6000 rows. In my code I first filter out some rows.

```
Sheets("privata").Rows("2:" & Rows.count).AutoFilter Field:=26, Criteria1:=">=2020-01-30  09:00:00", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=2020-01-30  09:30:00"
Sheets("privata").Rows("2:" & Rows.count).AutoFilter Field:=24, Criteria1:="<>OK"
Sheets("privata").Rows("2:" & Rows.count).AutoFilter Field:=25, Criteria1:="<>SUPPLY_CONTROL,"
```

Its now down to about 350 rows. After I've filtered it I copy and paste the data to another sheet

```
Sheets("privata").UsedRange.Copy
Sheets("toptre").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

After I've copied the data I work on it in various ways in the new sheet.

The entire code takes a while to run. After stepping through the code I discovered that the filtering out process is super quick. What takes time is the pasting of the data in to the other sheet.

Is there a possibility to work with the original filtered sheet? When I try to, it uses all 6000 rows, not just the filtered out ones.

Example of what I want to do:

```
For i = 2 To RowCount + 1
employee = Sheets("privata").Cells(i, 25)
onList = False
    For j = 1 To UBound(employeeList)

            If employee = employeeList(j) Then
                onList = True
                Exit For
            End If
    Next j
If onList = False Then
countEmployees = countEmployees + 1
employeeList(countEmployees) = employee
End If
If onList = True Then
onList = False
End If
Next i
```

When referring to Cells(2, 25) I want to refer to the second row in the filtered sheet. Which might be row 3568 in the sheet. Is that possible?

/Jens

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the range of the visible rows after applying an advanced filter in Excel (VBA)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1370286/11683)

Comment: That didn't solve my problem. But maybe I'm using it wrong. I'll edit the question with an example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the filtering has been applied, you can make the copy/paste process very fast if you don't use a loop, but use `Selection`.  For example:

```
Sub TryThis()
    Dim r As Range
    Sheets("privata").Select
    Set r = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
    r.Select
    Selection.Copy Sheets("toptre").Range("A1")
End Sub
```

Usually you want to avoid `Selection` in VBA.  However, you will end up with:

- a block of data in sheet *"toptre"*
- the block will include the header row and all visible rows
- the block will be just a block *(un-filtered)*

Comment: Wow that was super quick, like under half a second! Compared to like 5-6 seconds with the copy paste method! That really solved my problem!

Comment: Super weird problem. When using it on some sheets I get an "Object variable not set" error even though the code is the same. Do you have any clue why?

Comment: Set rng = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range is the line that produces the error

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will make your process any faster, but it attempts to accomplish what you ask about in your question:

You could use the expression suggested by @GSerg 's comment to create a range object with only the visible rows in the data sheet, e.g.

```
Dim filteredRange As Range
Set filteredRange = Sheets("privata").UsedRange.Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Assuming there is at least 1 visible row in the sheet (meaning that the above statement will not throw an error), you could then use the following function to access that range as if it were a single, contiguous range:

```
Function RelativeCell(rng As Range, ByVal row As Long, ByVal col As Long) As Range
    Dim areaNum As Long: areaNum = 0
    Dim maxRow As Long: maxRow = 0

    Dim areaCount As Long: areaCount = rng.Areas.Count
    Do While maxRow < row
        areaNum = areaNum + 1
        If areaNum > areaCount Then
            Set RelativeCell = Nothing
            Exit Function
        End If

        maxRow = maxRow + rng.Areas(areaNum).Rows.Count
    Loop

    Dim lastArea As Range: Set lastArea = rng.Areas(areaNum)
    Set RelativeCell = lastArea.Cells(row - (maxRow - lastArea.Rows.Count), col)
End Function
```

To print all the filtered values in column B, for example, you could use the above method on the `filteredRange` object (set earlier) this way:

```
    Dim r As Long: r = 1
    Do
        Dim cell As Range: Set cell = RelativeCell(filteredRange, r, 2)
        If cell Is Nothing Then Exit Do

        Debug.Print cell.Value
        r = r + 1
    Loop
```

To simplify the above code, you could also use a function to know the last relative row number in the filtered range using the following function:

```
Function RelativeCellLastRow(rng As Range) As Long
    Dim r As Long: r = 0

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To rng.Areas.Count
        r = r + rng.Areas(i).Rows.Count
    Next

    RelativeCellLastRow = r
End Function
```

Then, the code to print all the filtered values in column B would be reduced to this:

```
    Dim r As Long
    For r = 1 To RelativeCellLastRow(filteredRange)
        Debug.Print RelativeCell(testRng, r, 2).Value
    Next
```

If you use `RelativeCellLastRow`, it would be good to ensure that it is only executed once, to avoid unnecessary recalculations. In the `For` loop above, it is only executed once, since VBA only executes the limits of a `For` loop before the first iteration. If you need the value several times, you can store it in a variable and use the variable instead.

The idea behind the `RelativeCell` function is that the range returned by the call to `SpecialCells` is a multi-area range, i.e. a range made up of several non-contiguous ranges. What `relativeCell` does is to skip through the non-contiguous areas until it finds the row number it is looking for. If the row number is beyond the total number of rows in the range, the function returns `Nothing`, so the calling code must be aware of this to avoid calling a method or property on `Nothing`.

It is also worth nothing that `RelativeCell` works on a range with hidden rows, not hidden columns. With hidden columns, the code becomes a little more complex, but the complexity can be encapsulated in the `RelativeCell` function without affecting the code that uses the function.

Again, I am not sure whether this will make your code faster. When I did some tests to emulate your scenario using a sheet with 6000+ rows and 30 columns of random strings, the copy/paste after the filtering ran very quickly, but it could be because of the machine I am using, the version of Excel that I am using (2016), or the data I used. Having said that, I hope the above code is of some help.

Comment: Wow thank you for that awesome answer! Learned a lot reading it! Although I think I'll go with Gary's Students answer above. But if I ever need to work on a filtered sheet I'll use your solution!